# can't show results on google maps location finder

Tags: google-maps

i have created a script for a store finder in Canada (Calgary - Montreal).it was working fine till i added more stores to the database.

this is the page of the map
http://www.soshapal.com/Map/montreal/food%20and%20drinks
i use those to postal code for testing (H3G 1W6 - H3H 1M1)
the first one works fine but the second one doesn't

i also noticed that the behavior changes if i change the limit in this query

> SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) )
>   * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM address           WHERE business_id IN
>   (SELECT id FROM business_pages            WHERE country_id = {$country_id}
>             AND (city_id = {$city_id} OR city_id = 0) 
>             AND section_id = {$section_id}          )
>             HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20", mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
>   mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
>   mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
>   mysql_real_escape_string($radius))

does anyone know why this happening?

Comment: Most likely a problem in your data.

Comment: The first postcode (H3G 1W6) gives me: "There are no businesses in the area specified.", you are saying that is correct?

Comment: For some queries your XML is invalid.